# Как пишется частица "не" с прилагательными?

Tags: орфография, частица-не

"Если каблук невысокий, то ходить будет удобно".

Answer (score 1):

Не с прилагательными пишется слитно, если образуется новое слово, которое можно заменить синонимом (в Вашем случае невысокий-низкий, еще примеры  неинтересный - скучный) и при этом в предложении нет противопоставления с союзом "а" (не высокий, а низкий каблук) и нет слов совсем не, ничуть не, вовсе не, отнюдь не (совсем не высокий каблук, ничуть не страшный фильм).